# When using pin payment gateway , using charge api showing error Card tokens can only be used once

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am getting the following error when I use [this API](https://test-api.pin.net.au/1/charges):

> {"error":"token_already_used","error_description":"Token already used.
>   Card tokens can only be used once, to create a charge or assign a card
>   to a customer"}

I have a card token `card_4KDerBMsGjr0Rns3rNfwCQresult` which I have used in the charge API for making payments.

My account is in test mode, but when I check the dashboard page of my account in the charges page it shows that the credit card has been charged, so why am I not getting any successful response?

I have followed [the docs](https://pin.net.au/docs/guides/payment-forms) from the website only. I am novice, using this payment gateway for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed out this problem of mine . I called exec() function twice using curl  , that was the reason this error was shown